# MySQL - Counting two things with different conditions

Tags: mysql, count

I want to count two things under different conditions in one query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_name WHERE name = ?
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table_name WHERE address = ? AND port = ?
```

I need to have a count for rows that have a certain address and certain port, and a SEPARATE count for rows that have a certain name.

I'm aware that I could do

```
SELECT (COUNT*) as count FROM table_name WHERE (address = ? AND port = ?) OR name = ?
```

However that is a single count, and I need them to be separate so I can display a more accurate message to the user.

How might I go about doing this? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What about simply:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(name = ?, 1, 0)) AS name_count,
    SUM(IF(address = ? AND port = ?, 1, 0)) AS addr_count
FROM 
    table_name
```

Comment: I think this would be about the same as bobwienholt's in terms of performance, but if one of `name`, `address` or `port` are indexed, it may be faster to add these conditions to the WHERE clause as well: `WHERE name = ? OR (address = ? AND port = ?)`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Name = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as name_match
       , SUM(CASE WHEN Address = ? AND Port = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as address_match
FROM table_name
WHERE (address = ? AND port = ?) OR name = ?
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this query would be faster than the other two solutions. Would you agree?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT( CASE WHEN n1 = 'J' THEN 1 END ) AS t1,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN n2 = 'C' THEN 1 END ) AS t2,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN n3 = 'K' THEN 1 END ) AS t3 
FROM test
```

Using `COUNT(CASE...)`, you can get the count of two-column from single table, even when conditions for both are different (eg: Get count of J from n1 column and count of C from n2 column, and so on..)

Table: test

```
+----+----+----+----+
| id | n1 | n2 | n3 |
|----+----+----+----+
|  1 | J  | C  | K  |
|----+----+----+----+
|  1 | J  | C  | F  |
|----+----+----+----+
|  1 | J  | K  | C  |
|----+----+----+----+
|  1 | K  | K  | C  |
|----+----+----+----+
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+
| t1 | t2 | t3 |
|----+----+----+
|  3 | 2  | 1  |
|----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be easiest just to do a *Union*:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_name WHERE name = ? 
    GROUP BY name
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table_name WHERE address = ? AND port = ?
    GROUP BY address, port
```

Comment: I've never actually used a UNION before, but I'm thinking that @bobwienholt's query would be faster. What do you think?

Comment: @DrAgonmoray It's a good question, and I don't really know ... I'm actually inclined to think this way would be faster **if** there's an index on *name* as well as *address* or *port*.  Count is very fast for an indexed column, whereas adding a case statement might require a scan of all the rows.  YMMV :)

Comment: I tend to agree with dbaseman's assessment.  However, I tend to use my method in queries where the WHERE clause is looking at columns different then the ones I'm counting values in.  In that case, my method would probably be faster.

Comment: Hmm, good to know. Here's a question: if indexing columns makes things faster, not index everything? (Probably because then it would just be like a normal table) So here's a better question: Where do I draw the line concerning how many/what rows I index?

Comment: However now that I think about it this query is the only time I'll be counting those rows, so indexing them would be a bit useless.

Comment: @DrAgonmoray Yeah, it's always a trade-off with indices.  Adding an index makes every insert operation a bit slower, and takes up more disk space.  So you have to add them judiciously.

Comment: @McGarnagle I am doing the same but I am getting error `SELECT COUNT(ims.installation_id) AS total_images
FROM installation_images_site ims
INNER JOIN installation ins ON ins.id = ims.installation_id
WHERE ims.installation_id = 1 
GROUP BY ims.installation_id
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ims.image_name) AS images_uploaded
WHERE ims.image_upload_flag = 1
GROUP BY ims.image_name`

Comment: @McGarnagle the error I am getting is `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near where ims.image_upload_flag= 1
group by ims.image_name
 LIMIT 0, 1000 at line 8`