# Counting all rows in column with two different date conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, mariadb

I'm trying to turn two count queries with date conditions (the ones below) into one query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as yesterday FROM orders WHERE DATE(timedate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
SELECT COUNT(*) as yesterday FROM orders WHERE DATE(timedate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

[Following the advice of another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576435/mysql-counting-two-things-with-different-conditions) I created the following, but that doesn't seem to work syntax-wise, and I'm not quite sure why. Is there another way to do this? I can't find a similar question on this

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(DATE(timedate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) AS testcount1,
    SUM(IF(DATE(timedate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY))) AS testcount2
FROM 
    orders
```

Comment: 'I'm not quite sure why' - you didn't transcribe the if function correctly also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation. I would phrase the query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        timedate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        and timedate < CURRENT_DATE
    ) AS testcount1,
    SUM(
        timedate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
        and timedate < CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL 1 DAT
    ) AS testcount2
FROM orders
```

Details:

- this uses a nice feature of MySQL, that evaluates false/true conditions as `0/1` in numeric context
- no date functions are applied on the `timedate` column : instead, we do litteral date comparisons. This is much more efficient, since the database can possibly take advantage of an index on the datetime column

You might also want to add a `WHERE` clause to the query:

```
WHERE 
    timedate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 day
    AND timedate< CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the output values for the `IF` expression. Also you should use `CURRENT_DATE()` so you don't need to convert to a `DATE`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(DATE(timedate) = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1, 0)) AS testcount1,
    SUM(IF(DATE(timedate) = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 1, 0)) AS testcount2
FROM 
    orders
```

Note that MySQL treats boolean expressions as `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`) in a numeric context, so you can actually `SUM` the expression without needing the `IF`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DATE(timedate) = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS testcount1,
    SUM(DATE(timedate) = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS testcount2
FROM 
    orders
```